# python 3.x urllib.request.HTTPSHandler override METHOD GET POST

Tags: python, python-3.x, https, urllib

```
context = ssl.create_default_context()
context.load_cert_chain(certificate, pkey)
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPSHandler(context=context))
response = opener.open(url, data=None)
print(response.read())
```

Executing the above code with data=None automatically sets the METHOD to GET, while setting data to anything else automatically sets the METHOD to POST.

Is there a way to override this behavior?

According to the docs you can use Request.method, but I'm not understanding how to reference that from 'opener'.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html

> Request.method
>
> The HTTP request method to use. By default its value is None, which means that get_method() will do its normal computation of the method to be used. Its value can be set (thus overriding the default computation in get_method()) either by providing a default value by setting it at the class level in a Request subclass, or by passing a value in to the Request constructor via the method argument.
>
> New in version 3.3.
>
> Changed in version 3.4: A default value can now be set in subclasses; >previously it could only be set via the constructor argument.

"method should be a string that indicates the HTTP request method that will be used (e.g. 'HEAD'). If provided, its value is stored in the method attribute and is used by get_method(). The default is 'GET' if data is None or 'POST' otherwise. Subclasses may indicate a different default method by setting the method attribute in the class itself."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the [`urllib.request.Request`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request) you can use the `method` argument to set the specific `method` you want for this request:

> class urllib.request.Request(url, data=None, headers={}, origin_req_host=None, unverifiable=False, **method=None**)

However - when you use the [`opener`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.OpenerDirector.open) you can't provide the `method`:

> OpenerDirector.open(url, data=None[, timeout])

There is no `method` argument for the `open` method.

What you can do - is create a `Request` object and use the `opener` to send that request:

```
req = urllib.request.Request(url, method='POST')
res = opener.open(req)
print(res.read())
```